# Raster Properties to TextFile using ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, raster, for-loop, valueerror

I have multiple rasters that I want to get the mean of the all the cells. This is what I have:

```
env.workspace = r"C:\Users\pyb609\Desktop\Updated 
Files\GIS\Dark\Shapefiles\15M"
outfile = open(r"C:\Users\pyb609\Desktop\UpdatedFiles\GIS\Dark\Shapefiles\15M\15M_Mean.txt", 'w')

#Check out the Arcgis Spatial Anaylst extension licence
arcpy.CheckOutExtension("Spatial")

# Get a list of Rasters
rasterList = arcpy.ListDatasets("*","Raster")    

for inRaster in rasterList:
    # just to view progress
    print inRaster
    outfile.write(inRaster)

    Mean =arcpy.GetRasterProperties_management(inRaster, "MEAN")
    textinfo =(inRaster, Mean)
    textstring =str(textinfo)
    outfile.write(textstring)
    outfile.close()
```

It gives me the first file but then I get an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last): 
File "C:\Users\pyb609\Desktop\Updated Files\GIS\Dark\MeanRaster.py", line 26, in <module> outfile.write(inRaster) 

ValueError: I/O operation on closed file
```

Answer (score 2):

You are closing your `outfile` in the loop iteration. Either close it *after* the loop or use a `with` statement. Also, you should use `.getOutput()` to get the actual value from the `GetRasterProperties` tool.

Something like:

```
env.workspace = r"C:\Users\pyb609\Desktop\Updated Files\GIS\Dark\Shapefiles\15M"

#Check out the Arcgis Spatial Analyst extension licence
arcpy.CheckOutExtension("Spatial")

# Get a list of Rasters
rasterList = arcpy.ListDatasets("*","Raster")    

with open(r"C:\Users\pyb609\Desktop\UpdatedFiles\GIS\Dark\Shapefiles\15M\15M_Mean.txt", 'w') as outfile:

    for inRaster in rasterList:
        # just to view progress
        print inRaster

        Mean =arcpy.GetRasterProperties_management(inRaster, "MEAN").getOutput(0)

        textinfo = (inRaster, Mean)
        textstring = '%s, %s\n' % textinfo
        outfile.write(textstring)
```